# Maximizing parallel http requests on OS-X

Tags: macos, unix

I have to scrape thousands of different websites, as fast as possible. With my app running on a single process I was able to fetch 10 urls per second. Though if I fork it to 10 worker processes, I can reach 64 reqs/sec.

Why is so? Why I am limited to 10 reqs/sec on a single process and have to spawn workers to reach 64 reqs/sec

- I am not reaching max sockets/host limit: all urls are from unique hosts.
- I am not reaching max file descriptors limit (AFAIK): my ulimit -n is 2560, and lsof shows that my scraper never uses more than 20 file descriptors.
- I've increased settings for kern.maxfiles, kern.maxfilesperproc, kern.ipc.somaxconn, and kern.ipc.maxsockets in sysctl.conf, and rebooted. No effect.
- Tried increasing ulimit -n. No change.

Is there any limit I don't know about?

Comment: Are you doing this directly on top of BSD sockets, or are you using some higher-level API or library?

Comment: Without knowing how Node implements its HTTP requests on OS X, it's hard to know what limit you're hitting. It may be worth doing some tests using lower-level APIs on OS X, or Node on other platforms.